# I tried this code in python with OpenCV, but I don't understand the error message

Tags: python, opencv

I used this code in python with OpenCV, but I don't understand the error. Would someone please explain the meaning of the error message?

```
img = cv2.imread('img.png',0)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap='gray')
plt.title('laplacian')


laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)

error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:760: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function cv::Mat::locateROI
```

Answer (score 2):

You are starting your subplot at 2 plots and only show one image. So it should be 2,2,1 not 2,2,2. And you are adding your title after you display the image. It should be before.

You have to add your image to the subplot in an implicit figure with plt.imshow() and then to actually display the figure, use plt.show(). (You can also create a specifically named figure first and then create subplots for it.)

Try this:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# read image and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('img.png',0)

# compute laplacian
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)


# show both original and laplacian using pyplot
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original')
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian')
plt.show()

# show just laplacian using pyplot
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian')
plt.show()

# or show just laplacian with no subplot specification or title
plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()

# show laplacian using OpenCV
cv2.imshow("Laplacian", laplacian)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please review:

[pyplot subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

[simple examples to display images](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/03/display-matplotlib-rgb-image/)